# Why does't my code disable the mousewheel event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

When I scroll on chrome, I get error in my website.

**jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312**

To prevent this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).on("mousewheel", function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    } else if (e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY < 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }    

});
 });
```

used this in layout/master page.

But it has no effect and error doesn't go off.

Answer (score 5):

You should set the parameter "passive" in options to "false"

[MDN addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

> passive: A Boolean which, if true, indicates that the function specified by listener will never call preventDefault(). If a passive listener does call preventDefault(), the user agent will do nothing other than generate a console warning. See Improving scrolling performance with passive listeners to learn more.

```
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: Paste to the Chrome console and you will see it works fine with out error

Comment: hi, it does. Even in console and doesn't remove the error too.

Comment: it says undefined

Comment: undefined is not an error. after paste the code to console, check the web page by using the mouse-wheel.

Comment: it still works, mouse wheel and error is also there

Comment: did you paste it to the Chrome console(F12)?

Comment: Hi, it worked and screen jerks are gone but the error is still there. But thats ok